# How to build a tab-delimited text file with many calculated values?

Tags: bash, dataframe, text-processing

## Background

From a set of similar reference files (sample1.txt, sample2.txt, etc.), I am calculating or retrieving data for many different parameters (pc.genes, pc.transcripts, pc.genes.antisense, etc.).

A simplified **example** of a single `ref.file` (e.g., sample1.txt):

```
word1   word2   word3   405438   409170   .   Y   .   word4; word5
word1   word2   word3   405438   409170   .   N   .   word4; word5
word1   word2   word3   409006   409170   .   N   .   word4; word5
word1   word2   word3   405438   408401   .   Y   .   word4; word5
word1   word2   word3   407099   408361   .   N   0   word4; word5
```

---

A calculation for “avg.exons” parameter might look like:

```
$ awk '$3 == "word3"' sample1.txt | sed -n 's/.*word4 \([^;]*\).*word5 \([^;]*\).*/\1;\2/p' | awk -F';' '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) {count++; sum += a[i]} print sum/count}'
5.96732
```

A retrieval for “pc.genes” parameter might look like:

```
$ awk '$3 == "word3"' sample1.txt | grep -c "word4"
19062
```

These are just examples in case the solution requires the commands to be piped to a function that transfers/adds them to a table. The output value of these commands is *always* a single number.

---

## Desired Output

I would like to put these calculated/retrieved values into an organized table format (preferably a tab-delimited text file) so that I can generate plots from the data:

```
ref.file    pc.genes    pc.transcripts  pc.genes.antisense  pc.genes.sense  avg.exons   avg.genelength
sample1.txt 19062   116573  2585576 1318321 5.96732 3732.57
sample2.txt 19753   138563  5834759 1433785 5.84654 4023.89
sample3.txt 19376   124576  2871235 1983263 6.78929 3890.32
```

Is this possible? And if so, how can I achieve this?

## Attempt

```
for file in sample*.txt
do
    printf "%s\n" ref.file pc.genes pc.transcripts pc.genes.antisense pc.genes.sense avg.exons avg.genelength | paste -sd $'\t'
    pc.genes=$(awk '$3 == "word3"' ${file} | grep -c "word4")
    avg.exons=$(awk '$3 == "word3"' ${file} | sed -n 's/.*word4 \([^;]*\).*word5 \([^;]*\).*/\1;\2/p' | awk -F';' '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) {count++; sum += a[i]} print sum/count}')
    ... # get rest of desired values
done > table.txt
```

## Resulting Errors

```
-bash: pc.genes=19062: command not found
... # other errors with corresponding CORRECT value outputs
-bash: avg.exons=5.96732: command not found
... # the errors even continue into the other sample*.txt files, which is good
-bash: pc.genes=19753: command not found
...
```

All of the *values* corresponding to a given parameter (i.e., "`=###`") are correct, but the error is preventing them from being put in the table.

Comment: have you tried piping to `column -t` ?

Comment: This is not answering your question, but it's so cool! https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1CBDTgGtOU (After you get your CSV/TSV, you could use visidata)

About your question, I think that just using redirection operators can make a table. Search for 'bash redirect to file' 'bash input output redirections' and similar strings

Comment: you're actually searching for the literal strings `word1`, `word2` and `word3`?  consider reviewing [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and then come back and update your question accordingly; in particular ... sample data, explanation of what you're attempting to do (right now you have 2x different sets of commands so it's not clear how/when to apply each) and then for the sample dataset a) current (incorrect) output and b) desired (correct) output

Comment: @Jetchisel, I have not tried piping to ```column -t``` and @Vinko Vrsalovic I will look into these redirection operators and see if these work for me. I appreciate the help; your suggestions have already proven more helpful than my google searches of my question!! Also, very cool tool! Thanks for the share.

Comment: @markp-fuso, I hear you, however it is actually unimportant that the reader knows *how* I am calculating/retrieving my data, just that each of my calculations/retrievals *always* output a single number and I want that single number to be properly indexed in my table with the ```ref.file``` it came from and the corresponding header for that calculation/retrieval.
So, no, I am not searching literally for ```word1``` and such. Those are just examples of what I am doing to get the values that I ultimately want to end up in the final table.

Comment: by default `bash` does not allow periods in variable names; easiest solution: remove the periods (or replace with underscores); as for the other issues with the updated code attempt, see the latest comment on my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer works perfectly and comes from the combined suggestions of markp-fuso and KamilCuk. Thank you both!

```
# add the table headers
printf "%s\n" ref.file pc.genes pc.transcripts pc.genes.antisense pc.genes.sense avg.exons avg.genelength | paste -sd $'\t'

for file in sample*.txt
do
# create variables containing code for all parameter calculations/retrievals
pcgenes=$(awk '$3 == "word3"' ${file} | grep -c "word4")
pctranscripts=$(...)
pcgenesantisense=$(...)
pcgenessense=$(...)
avgexons=$(awk '$3 == "word3"' ${file} | sed -n 's/.*word4 \([^;]*\).*word5 \([^;]*\).*/\1;\2/p' | awk -F';' '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) {count++; sum += a[i]} print sum/count}')
avggenelength=$(...)

# print all resulting values in a single tab separated row of the table
printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" ${file} ${pcgenes} ${pctranscripts} ${pcgenesantisense} ${pcgenessense} ${avgexons} ${avggenelength}
done > table.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

Based solely on the details provided by the OP, and assuming a looping construct is being used to process a single file at a time, something like:

```
# print header
printf "ref.file\tpc.genes\tpc.transcripts\tpc.genes.antisense\tpc.genes.sense\tavg.exons\tavg.genelength\n"

while read -r fn
do
    aexons=$(awk '$3 == "word1"' ${fn} | sed -n 's/.*word2 \([^;]*\).*word3 \([^;]*\).*/\1;\2/p' | awk -F';' '{a[$1]++}END{for (i in a) {count++; sum += a[i]} print sum/count}')
    pgenes=$(awk '$3 == "word1"' ${fn} | grep -c "word2")
    ... # get rest of desired values

    # print tab-delimited output to stdout; adjust formats as needed
    printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n" ${fn} ${pgenes} .... ${axeons} ...

done < <('ls' sample*.txt)  # replace with whatever logic OP is using to find desired files
```

---

While the above should work, it's not very efficient what with all of the subprocess calls (`$(...)`; piped commands), and the need to process each input file (`${fn}`) 6x times (for 6x values).

A more efficient method would look at processing each input file (`${fn}`) just once.

An additional step might be to eliminate the loop in favor of a single program to process all files in one pass.

Since `awk` is capable of parsing data (from multiple files), calculating sums/averages, and generating (tab-delimited) output, I'd probably be leaning towards a single `awk` command/invocation as a more efficient solution ... but can't tell for sure without sample data and more details on the desired calculations.

Comment: `", ${fn},` - well, there are no commas in shell when passing arguments. (But I know, my muscle memory  sometimes writes `,` in shell). There is a simpler way, it's `printf "%s\n" ref.file pc.gens etc | paste -sd $'\t'`. As to `<('ls' sample*.txt)` note that we [should not parse ls](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead). Would be better to `<(printf "%s\n" sample*.txt)` but the best just do `for fn in sample*.txt; do`.

Comment: **arg**, thanks ... was jumping between `awk` and `bash`; fixed

Comment: ummm ... you've mangled the answer quite a bit which would explain the undesired output you're now generating; re: your updated question: 1) the `printf` for the header record goes outside/before the loop since you only want to print that **once**
 (see my answer), 2) your updated code does not include the `printf` for printing out values (see last line in `for` loop in my answer) and 3) `bash` does not, by default, allow periods in a variable name (yes, it's possible to include a period but it's a convoluted process; best to remove the periods or replace with underscores)